# Passing arguments to a page

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I've a page (i.e. under Pages directory) called `dettaglio_regione.ctp`. I want to set URLs like `http://.../clienti/[[regione]]`, so a working URL should be something like `http://.../clienti/Campania` or `http://.../clienti/Sicilia` and so on.
I need to grab the content of `[[regione]]`. How I've to set the route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Router::connect('/clienti/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

and then make your action have the following signature

```
// In your PagesController.php
function display($regione){
    ...//What ever you want to do
}
```

EDIT : changed yourActionName to display to fit the OP situation better

Comment: action is already set to 'display', a default action that just show page, i have no need to call a particular action.

Comment: then just instead of writing `yourActionName` write `display`